# How does the graph of money supply of PPCoin look like?

Tags: peercoin

We all know how the [money supply graph in Bitcoin looks like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTotal_bitcoins_over_time.png) - exponentially reaching 21,000,00 BTC.

How does the same graph behave for [PPCoin](http://ppcoin.org/) (A fork that also involves Proof Of Stake)?

Comment: Why the vote to close? (alternative crypto-currencies are on-topic)

Comment: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=122467.0

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

[image: Peercoin Total Money Supply]

Note that this chart goes only up to March 2014. In the future, when proof of stake dominates, there will be a steady 1% inflation every year, but also 0.01 PPC will be destroyed every transaction. It is not known exactly what will happen, i.e. whether the 1% inflation or the destruction of coins every transaction will be a more significant factor.

Comment: In case you didn't know, it is possible to attach pictures to posts here on Stackexchange.

Comment: I have amended it.